# How to specify exceptions for PascalCase naming rule in SonarLint

Tags: c#, sonarlint

According to [RSPEC-101](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-101), types should be named in PascalCase. I use the same convention but a lot of types in my codebase have acronyms in their name (e.g. ABCBase, ABCSomeName, ABSSomeOtherName, and so on). Is there any way to configure SonarLint in Visual Studio to treat "ABC" as an acronym and accept ABCSomeName as a valid type name?

Comment: The example `ABC` is a little abstract, so here's a real world example. We use an implementation of `Data Distribution Service`, known as `DDS` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Distribution_Service). We have a `DDSConfiguration` class. However RSPEC-101 would have me call this thing `DataDistributionServiceConfiguration`. This is technically correct but the world always refers to the abbreviation so following the technical guidelines actually makes the code *less* readable to other developers. Finally the library we use also uses `DDS` everywhere. Not following their convention seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to downgrade acronyms and initialisms to only have the first character in uppercase when doing PascalCase symbols.

So NMEA in GetNMEAPosition would then be GetNmeaPosition.

This convention not only solves the problem with sonarlint S101 matching, but also makes PascalCase symbols easier to read - acronyms works well on their own, but not that well with PascalCase where the next word adds one more uppercase character.

This is Microsoft's view on spelling acronyms longer than 2 characters into camelcase:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/141e06ef(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

> - When using acronyms, use Pascal case or camel case for acronyms more than
>   two characters long. For example, use HtmlButton or htmlButton. However,
>   you should capitalize acronyms that consist of only two characters, such as
>   System.IO instead of System.Io.
> - Do not use abbreviations in identifiers or parameter names. If you must use
>   abbreviations, use camel case for abbreviations that consist of more than
>   two characters, even if this contradicts the standard abbreviation of the
>   word.

And a Google symbol name style guide:
https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

§6.3 Camel case:

> 1. Convert the phrase to plain ASCII and remove any apostrophes. For example,
>    Müller's algorithm might become Muellers algorithm.
> 2. Divide this result into words, splitting on spaces and any remaining
>    punctuation (typically hyphens).
>
>    - Recommended: if any word already has a conventional camel case appearance
>      in common usage, split this into its constituent parts (e.g., AdWords
>      becomes ad words). Note that a word such as iOS is not really in camel case
>      per se; it defies any convention, so this recommendation does not apply.
> 3. Now lowercase everything (including acronyms), then uppercase only the
>    first character of:
>
>    - … each word, to yield upper camel case, or
>    - … each word except the first, to yield lower camel case
> 4. Finally, join all the words into a single identifier.

Answer (score 0):

usually it's a bad idea to prefix the name of a class (as is mentioned in clean code)

> **Don’t add gratuitous context**
>
> In an imaginary application called “Foo
> Solution” it is a bad idea to prefix every class with FS. Frankly, you
> are working against your tools. You type ‘F’ and press the completion
> key and are bombarded with a mile-long list of every class in the
> system.

https://medium.com/mindorks/meaningful-names-a-dimension-of-writing-clean-code-fdae1ae4f0b1

Comment: Well yes but actually no :) In our case, ABC (and a few more acronyms) are well understood in the team and it makes sense to have those few exceptions (in some cases, I don't even remember their long versions anymore :D). Besides, I don't have the power to convince my team lead and the entire team to rename hundreds of classes :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on github: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/273

Snippets from the page (dated 2018, snipped in 2022):

> Is there a way of adding exceptions to this rule?
> For example, I would like that GMTService not fail this rule as "GMT" is a keyword which I want to ignore.

And

> There is no such feature of exclusion list but depending on your usage, you can either:
> if paired with SonarQube/SonarCloud mark the issue as False Positive or Won't Fix on the server side
> if you are only using the analyzer, exclude the issue using a pragma